# How to display dynamic datepicker

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an input which has name="datepicker" as identifier. This is inside of a while loop to generate dynamic data. The problem is, the datepicker only works on the first input. How do i correct this?.

this is my blade

```
    <div class="row">
    @foreach ($kelas as $x)
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                @include('flashmessage')
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p style="font-weight: 800;"> Nama Kelas : {{ $x->nama_kelas }} - {{ $x->matkul }} </p>
                    <p style="font-weight: 800;"> Nama Modul : {{ $x->modul }} </p>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Tanggal Praktek</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd M, yyyy" data-date-format="dd M, yyyy" 
                                                data-date-container='#datepicker' data-provide="datepicker" id="datepicker{{$x->id_modulkelas}}">

                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div><!-- input-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

so it will create much row with datepicker input as much as data in $kelas.
and this is my js script

```
    <script>
    $( function() {
      $( "#datepicker{{$x->id_modulkelas}}" ).datepicker();
    } );
</script>
```

i've been try to add unique id using as we can see up there.
Right now the datepicker only appears in first row input, but when i clicked another input the datepicker doesn't want to appears.How to make datepicker appears in all row input?

[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using the same ID for all your datepicker inputs, which might be causing the problem. IDs should be unique. Try modifying your blade file like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($kelas as $x)
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                @include('flashmessage')
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p style="font-weight: 800;"> Nama Kelas : {{ $x->nama_kelas }} - {{ $x->matkul }} </p>
                    <p style="font-weight: 800;"> Nama Modul : {{ $x->modul }} </p>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label class="form-label">Tanggal Praktek</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="dd M, yyyy" data-date-format="dd M, yyyy" data-date-container='#datepicker1' data-provide="datepicker">
                                <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                            </div><!-- input-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And your script like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```